# I can't align an icon and its text within a menu item

Tags: html, css, web

as a new person dealing with HTML5 + CSS3 I am struggling with menus, text and icon aligments within the menu.
This the scenario: Each line of the menu has an icon and a text (description). The problem is that I can't get them separated enough from each other to make it more readable. They appear too close and I want to have spaces between them.
Below is the html and css3 code, thanks in advance

Best!

HTML code

```
<div id="sidebar">
    <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="#" class="home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="explore">Explore</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="users">   Users</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="signout">   Sign Out</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS3 code

```
 #sidebar {
    position: absolute;
    right: -240px;
    background: #DF314D;  
    width: 240px;
    height: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 4px;

}

#sidebar ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
#sidebar ul li {
    margin: 0;

}
#sidebar ul li a {
    padding: 15px 20px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 100;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #C9223D;

    /* .....some transitions */
}


menu a.home {

    display: inline-block;
    background: url(../imagenes/bpi.png) no-repeat left;

    padding-right: 20px; /*no luck with this line */
 }

.menu a.explore { 
    display: inline-block;
     background: url(../imagenes/gasi.png) no-repeat left;
 }

.menu a.users { 
    display: inline-block;
    background: url(../imagenes/bicici.png) no-repeat left; 
}

.menu a.signout { 
    display: inline-block;
    background: url(../imagenes/bai.png) no-repeat left; 
}
```

Comment: What size are those images supposed to be?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming from the padding you were trying to apply that the background images should have been ~20px wide, this should work:

http://jsfiddle.net/5djz5kLk/

```
#sidebar ul li a {

    /* Add more left padding */
    padding: 15px 20px 15px 35px;

    /* the rest... */
}

/* 
  Set the background position with a pixel amount.
  The first value is the horizontal position, with the second
  being the vertical.
*/
.menu a.home {
    display: inline-block;
    background: url('http://placehold.it/20x20') no-repeat 10px center;
 }

/* repeat the above for each class */
```

If you simply use `left`, the horizontal position is the left edge. Using a pixel value (or any numeric unit, really) lets you set an offset from the left edge.

Comment: Your example works too, as I said before I need practice with those concept. Thanks so much for your example and explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add padding and do some modification in your code,i have done changes in your code, please follow below link for result

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anjum121/8f07jk2o/)

```
<div id="sidebar">
<ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#" class="home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="explore">Explore</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="users">   Users</a></li>
</ul>
```

css code

```
#sidebar {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    background: #DF314D;
    width: 240px;
    height: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
#sidebar ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
#sidebar ul li {
    margin: 0
}
#sidebar ul li a {
    padding: 15px 20px 15px 30px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 100;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #C9223D;
}
#sidebar ul li a:hover {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
#sidebar ul li a.home {
    background: url(https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/google-material-design-icons/48/ic_home_48px-20.png) no-repeat 5px 10px;
}
#sidebar ul li a.explore {
    background: url(https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/google-material-design-icons/48/ic_home_48px-20.png) no-repeat 5px 10px;
}
#sidebar ul li a.users {
    background: url(https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/google-material-design-icons/48/ic_home_48px-20.png) no-repeat 5px 10px;
}
```

Comment: I need to understand how the padding concept works along with another properties or so. Your example was very helpful.